# Avoid code duplication in OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I currently have a service that loads preferences upon startup, stores them as fields, then registers an `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` to update the fields when a preference is modified. Currently, my code looks like this:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private int _prefA;
    private boolean _prefB;
    private String _prefC;
    private boolean _prefD;
    private SharedPreferences _preferences;
    private SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener _prefChangeListener;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        _preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        _prefA = Integer.parseInt(_preferences.getString(PREF_A_KEY, "0"));
        _prefB = _preferences.getBoolean(PREF_B_KEY, false);
        _prefC = _preferences.getString(PREF_C_KEY, null);
        _prefD = _preferences.getBoolean(PREF_D_KEY, false);
        _prefChangeListener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
                if (key.equals(PREF_A_KEY)) {
                    _prefA = Integer.parseInt(sharedPreferences.getString(key, "0"));
                } else if (key.equals(PREF_B_KEY)) {
                    _prefB = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);
                } else if (key.equals(PREF_C_KEY)) {
                    _prefC = sharedPreferences.getString(key, null);
                } else if (key.equals(PREF_D_KEY)) {
                    _prefD = sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, false);
                }
            }
        };
        _preferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(_prefChangeListener);
    }
}
```

It works as expected, but adding more preferences is becoming tedious, since I have to update the code in both `onCreate()` and `OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`. Is there any way to change this so that the code to load the preferences only needs to be written once?

Comment: good question, I do the same silly thing ))

Comment: I do not see how it can be improved. May be creating a wrapper entity for settings encapsulating default values, most annoying part of the code. Other part is OK, since variable initialization and change tracking are different things. The wrapper class could have methods like getPreferenceAKey(), getPreferenceBKey(), etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is rather ideal. However, it reduced the overhead a little:

Create initializer functions:

```
private void initializeAccounts() {
    ...

    Resources res = getResources();
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String User = preferences.getString(res.getString(R.string.username), null);
    String Pass = preferences.getString(res.getString(R.string.password), null);
    ...
}
```

And then group the preferences :

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
    if (getString(R.string.prefkey_password).equals(key) || getString(R.string.prefkey_username).equals(key)) {
        initializeAccounts();
    }
}
```

In the `onCreate`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    initializeAccounts();
}
```

The reason why I group the preferences together is that the other preferences don't change when I edit one of them. However, when I for instance want to change the password of my account, I also require the other preferences like username or the server URI to reconnect to the server. So, it more or less doesn't matter if I reset them.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hmm, this works if the values are all related, but what if I want to load each preference separately? They can be modified from different locations, and I don't want to reload all preferences when only one has changed.

Comment: I re-read your code above and I was wondering why you are not using the preferences directly? If you don't start any action which is caused by the preference change, you may use the `preference.get*()` functions without storing them in the properties first.